# WCF WsDualHttpBinding. Не происходит возврат из метода

Tags: c#, callback, .net, iis, wcf

Добрый день!

Сервис WCF размещён в IIS. В нём изначально использовалась кастомная привязка:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Fetch" name="Tap.CADGIS.DesignerService.SubstratesDownloadProcess">
<endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BinaryHttpBinding" name="BinaryHttp" сontract="Tap.CADGIS.DesignerService.Interfaces.ISubstratesDownloadProcess" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
....
<behavior name="Fetch">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
...
<customBinding>
<binding name="BinaryHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
<binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"   maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binaryMessageEncoding>
<httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
</binding>
</customBinding>
```

Затем понадобилось изменить привязку, чтобы появилась возможность реализовать Callback, поэтому решил использовать привязку WsDualHttpBinding. Однако, изменив конфиг следующим образом:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Fetch"  name="Tap.CADGIS.DesignerService.SubstratesDownloadProcess">
<endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" name="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Tap.CADGIS.DesignerService.Interfaces.ISubstratesDownloadProcess" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

вылезла проблема: при попытке вызова метода сервиса управление в этот метод приходит, всё выполняется как надо, но после возврата управления из метода сервиса в клиент оно не возвращается, вместо этого клиент ожидает ответа, пока не будет сгенерировано исключение тайм-аута.

Гуглил на эту тему, однако ничего вразумительного не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Может дело в биндинге?

В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) написано, что дюплексный биндинг должен иметь адрес клиента для ответа ему, поэтому видимо нет ответа клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

На [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) говорится, что таймаут эксепшн это проблема авторизации:

> Недуплексные клиенты, которые не смогли пройти проверку с помощью
>   защищенного диалога, как правило, создают исключение
>   MessageSecurityException.Однако если дуплексному клиенту,
>   использующему защищенный диалог, не удается пройти проверку, клиент
>   получает вместо этого исключение TimeoutException.

Попробуйте задать правильный `<identity>` в конфиге клиента: [Переопределение идентификатора службы для проверки подлинности](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb628618(v=vs.110).aspx)